# Database check uniqueness before insert approach?

Tags: database, concurrency

*Edit: I think I need the code to speak for me...*

A simple example about my problem.

***Create a user in database, email and username are unique. If the uniqueness check does not pass, I need to know exactly which field/column/whatever is causing the error.***

***What I want to implement***

```
void createUser(String email, String username, String password) 
throws EmailExistingException, UsernameExistingException
{
    //TODO: Create the user or throw exception according to error.
}
```

**Bad approach**

```
void createUser(String email, String username, String password) 
throws EmailExistingException, UsernameExistingException
{
    //Do some query first.
    if (emailExists(email)) throw EmailExistingException;
    if (usernameExists(username)) throw UsernameExistingException;

    //TODO: Create the user.
}
```

What's wrong - Typical check before insert, never gonna be accepted.

**Not so bad approach**

```
//During database creation
db.users.setUnique("email", true);
db.users.setUnique("username", true);

void createUser(String email, String username, String password) 
throws UserCreationException
{
    try {
        //TODO: Create the user.
    } catch (SomeSortOfDatabaseException e) {
        throw UserCreationException("some message", e);
    }
}
```

What's not so good - It's likely I just get an exception with error code and string message. But I need to let users know the duplicated field so they can modify it accordingly, which I can't do it with this code. Maybe some db driver's errors can give you very specific details, but I think relying on the driver is not a good approach as it will kill you if you wanna change database in the future.

**My approach**

```
//During database creation
db.users.setUnique("email", true);
db.users.setUnique("username", true);

void createUser(String email, String username, String password) 
throws EmailExistingException, UsernameExistingException
{
    try {
        //TODO: Create the user.
    } catch (SomeSortOfDatabaseException e) {
        if (emailExists(email)) throw EmailExistingException;
        if (usernameExists(username)) throw UsernameExistingException;

        throw ServerException("some message", e);
    }
}
```

It's actually getting better but I do not like my current approach that much (in real world many of those unique fields can be changed, you know what I am saying). So I'm just curious what is the common approach for this problem in real production. Any opinions will be appreciated.

Comment: Which database? Some databases support this natively.

Comment: 'Some databases support this natively.' is definitely the problem I mentioned in that not so bad approach. Anyway I would love to hear which databases support that and how it's done, with thread safety of course.

Comment: mysql has `update ... on duplicate key ...` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use insert sql that has a built in atomic check:

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2, ...)
select * 
from (select 'foo', 'bar', ... from dual) x -- postgress, mysql, etc doesn't need "from dual"
left join mytable
    on col1 = 'foo'
   and col2 = 'bar'
   ...
where col1 is null -- only selects something when there's no match
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, I am actually looking for a more general approach. Regardless of it's sql or nosql database.

Comment: @toyknight There is no more "general approach" and specialization is required. Even the 'safety' of a given implementation within a specific (SQL) database implementation is at question: this problem-of-divergence is only compounded when expanding to "any" database type.

Comment: @toyknight it doesn't get any more general than this. This works for all databases and is atomic - no race conditions to worry about in multi-threaded environments (guaranteed by the relational database contract).

Comment: @Bohemian I know it is atomic. What I want to know is exactly which column is duplicated if the insertion is not successful. As far as I can remember, mysql driver only returns after update how many lines are affected?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution with Java.

```
//During database creation, make restrictions.

void createUser(String email, String username, String password) 
throws EmailExistingException, UsernameExistingException
{
    String email_intern = email.intern();
    String username_intern = username.intern();
    synchronized(email_intern) {
        synchronized(username_intern) {
            //Do some query first.
            if (emailExists(email)) throw EmailExistingException;
            if (usernameExists(username)) throw UsernameExistingException;

            //TODO: Create the user.
        }
    }
}
```

Seems quite promising. String.intern() ensures that same string value synchronizes on the same instance. This approach has very small impact on throughput while it gets rid of all the possible concurrency issues **of this method**.

**Notable things**

- Make sure that username is not in email pattern before passing here.
- It has only one possible lock order, no worry about dead lock issue.
- If such lock is also used in other methods, then must pay attention to lock order.
- Tripple check the JVM used for the server, be sure the interned String will be collected during GC.

Comment: You have *not* gotten rid of all possible concurrency issues. I assume your `emailExists` and `usernameExists` methods are both doing a query into the table. In between those two methods making their calls, another thread/process/app could be inserting/modifying/deleting email/password rows. This approach is okay to do, as it catches nearly all cases, but you must also implement the kind of atomic check shown in Answer by Bohemian.

Comment: @BasilBourque Agreed. But inserting the same email/username during existence checking is impossible due to the locks (assuming createUser is the only place where insert happens). For modifying we can do similar locking for all related methods (have to deal with lock order). Anyway making database restrictions is always good practice.